# .NET Detecting a Logon event in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, authentication, windows-10, sens

I've been getting a little stumped on this issue. I have a need to detect when a user logs on, when the Display is Locked, and when the user logs off. In the past I've used a VB.NET application which uses a COM reference to Sens ( System Event Notification Service ) which makes use of the Sens Events ISensLogon interface.

However, since moving to windows 10, I'm no longer able to add Sens as a COM object to my project. Is there an SDK that I'm missing in order to make use of this functionality?

Is there another COM library or reference that I need to use in order to detect these events in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch, AddressOf SystemEvents_SessionSwitch
End Sub

Private Sub SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(sender As Object, e As SessionSwitchEventArgs)

    Select Case e.Reason
        Case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock
            MessageBox.Show("Lock")
        Case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff
            MessageBox.Show("LogOff")
        Case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon
            MessageBox.Show("Login")
        Case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock
            MessageBox.Show("Unlock")
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub

End Class
```

Try to stay out of COM when and where the .NET framework makes that possible.