# Detect when the desktop is reached after a resume

Tags: vb.net, resume, windows-10-desktop

I can detect when Windows Resumes after a Suspend by:

```
AddHandler SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, AddressOf SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged
Private Sub SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
```

but if is set a PIN to access the Desktop... the event is generated **at the PIN request**, that can be several seconds or minutes before the Desktop is really opened.

**So the question is: how to detect if the Desktop has been really reached and the "usual" Desktop is really visible**?

I tried with:

```
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Friend Shared Function GetUserObjectInformation(ByVal hObj As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, 
       ByRef pvInfo As Long, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal nLength As Integer, 
          <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByRef lpnLengthNeeded As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Dim pvInfo As Long
    Dim lpnLenght As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To 50
        Sleep(1000)
        Debug.Print("Info: " & 
        NativeMethods.GetUserObjectInformation(DeskTopHwnd, 5, 
           pvInfo,Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Integer)), lpnLenght).ToString &
              " -" & lpnLenght.ToString)
    Next
```

... but the Debug.Print always gives: "**Info: False -0**", both at the PIN request and once reached the Desktop.

Comment: [GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo)

Comment: In the sense that I can get WHEN user types the PIN?? But this is NOT error proof: user can type ONE-TWO digits and then answer to the smartphone, without to enter in the Desktop... and I don't know how many digits has the PIN. Moreover... user can have NOT the PIN and to enter directly in the Desktop resuming from suspend mode...

Comment: Well, you could couple it with [GetMouseMovePointsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmousemovepointsex), to evaluate the mouse movements. Note that when the `PowerModeChanged` event reports an `e.Mode = PowerModes.Resume`, the desktop is already running (progman/explorer is running), so you should be able to hook whatever you're hooking. You haven't said what your hooks are for, so... BTW, `GetUserObjectInformation` requires a call to `OpenDesktop`, I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Hooks are shortcuts for a program of mine... and for some reason them stop to work after a long-time suspend. To make them already working i must unhook and hook again 6-8 seconds AFTER THE DESKTOP APPEARS (not the block screen, the desktop). GetMouseMovePoints is not error proof, since user can well move the mouse during the block screen to check where is the picture from and then answer to the smartphone for 20 minutes. I can get the Handle Text of the Block screen window, but I can't check it, since the text is in all the billion Win10 languages...

Comment: Try [SessionSwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44011764/2330053)?

Comment: SessionSwitch is the useful answer for me!! In fact the PowerModeChanged Resume mode is generated when is reached the Block screen, while the SessionUnlock mode is generated only after the Block Screen is closed. Ty. :)

Comment: Nice. Glad that was helpful. Be sure to up-vote the answer in the link then.  =)

Comment: The only (little) problem is that if the user sets Settings / Account / Sign-In Options / Require Sign-In on NEVER the SessionSwitch Event in NOT generated, so I must check both SessionSwitch and PowerModeChanged events. The sequence is 1) SessionSwitch.SessionLock  2) PowerModeChanged.Suspend 3) PowerModeChanged.Resume 4) SessionSwitch.SessionUnlock

Comment: Good to know!  Gotta love those edge cases...